# Retornar divs para a posição inicial

Tags: javascript, html, div

Neste momento a `drag3` volta sempre a posição inicial, exepto quando é colocada na `drop1`. No jogo completo tem 4 drag´s e 4 drop´s mas basta 1 de cada para o exemplo e dar a entender como tenho isto, penso eu.

O que quero mesmo, como já disse, é que voltem todas as drag´s a posição inicial sem dar refresh a pagina (que é o que faço nesse exemplo) quando clicar no botão/imagem de recomeçar.

```js
$("#drag3").draggable({
  revert: true,
  containment: "#fundo-interno"
});

$("#drop1").droppable({
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    if (ui.draggable.attr('id') == 'drag3') {
      $("#drag3").draggable({
        revert: false,
        containment: "#fundo-interno"
      });
      $(this)
        .addClass("alterar1")
        .find("p")
      alert("Muito Bem !");

    } else {
      $(this)
        .find("p")
      alert("Tenta denovo !");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#drag3 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 75px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  background-color: #727170;
  width: 45px;
  height: 45px;
}
#drop1 {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  width: 210px;
  height: 180px;
  float: left;
  background-position: center;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="reset" name="recomecar" value="Ok" id="recomecar" onclick="window.location.reload( true );">
<img src="seta.png" width="100px" height="100px">
```

Comment: Por favor, mostre o código que você já tem, e aponte o que está te trazendo dificuldade. Da forma como está, a pergunta certamente será fechada como "ampla demais". Fique à vontade para [edit] a pergunta com as informações relevantes.

Comment: Minha vista está doendo de tanto esforço para ler, poderia organizar a pergunta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você reparar, quando movimenta a `div` utilizando o `draggable` do jQuery UI, o elemento automaticamente recebe a posição como relativa, e então suas posições Top e Left são denominadas 0. Você pode utilizar isso ao seu favor, pois automaticamente a posição inicial do elemento será quando o mesmo estiver na posição *Top e Left: 0*. Logo, para fazer o elemento voltar a seu local de origem, pode simplesmente mandar o elemento para a posição *Top e Left: 0*. Para ele voltar com uma animação, pode usar a função `animate` do jQuery. Exemplo:

```
// "#reset" é o botão para resetar a posição do elemento
$("#reset").click(function() {
    $("#drag3").animate({
        top:"0",
        left:"0"
    }, 1000);
});
```

Veja um exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ejowy0j5/

Answer (score 0):

Guarde a posição `x` e `y` inicial das divs e entao quando precisar seta o valores do `left` e `top` dela.